# MVC3 correct way to change culture for every request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cultureinfo

I am using MVC3, and have some logic for changing the culture which all works fine. My issue, is that there seems a few places where this change should be made, and I am unsure where would be the best place to do it.

Some examples show an override on each action, from within a controller like this:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    // code to change culture
}
```

Whereas a more traditional way that I am used to seeing is doing it in the Global.asax file as follows:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // code to change culture
}
```

What is the recommended place to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

global.asax is the ASP.NET correct way of doing this. It works across frameworks (webforms, dynamic data,mvc).

Comment: Is there a proper way to stop the culture code being called for requests to things like images, CSS files, JavaScript etc

Comment: This in web.config:
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"/>
  </system.webServer>

Answer (score 4):

`Application_BeginRequest` is fine. If you set the culture on the thread there, the whole HTTP Request will be executed in that culture.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(myCulture);
```